# Run .m-file from python script in Linux

Tags: python, octave

I read the proposals but I dont found a answer.

How can I run a Octave .m-File from a python script in Linux?
Must I change the direction? 
I want to run the Octave .m-File with functions in the background without gui.

I try it with the os module from python:
(INFO: The .m-File run without bugs in octave)

```
import os
os.system("octave-cli /home/myscripts/test.m")
```

If I run this in the python console in spyder, I get "0" as output.
Normaly It must be "1" if have no bugs or? Must I make the test.m file executable?

Comment: Provide more information. Show code. You can run any CLI command in Python using the `subprocess` module. You can run Octave using CLI.

Comment: @TinNguyen see above.

Comment: system calls aside, the preferred way to run an octave script from inside python would be [oct2py](https://pypi.org/project/oct2py/). Lots of questions here on stackoverflow pointing out how to use it too.